# Which action/filter can i use for a Member Plugin

Tags: plugins, filters, actions, the-content, pre-get-posts

I'm a beginner in Wordpress Plugin development. I want to write a Plugin for a Member Part on my Page. I know, that Plugins for this Problem available, but i want to create an own Plugin ;)

I want to create a table in the database, who looks like:

```
ID | PostID | MemberOnly
```

So, i'm searching for an filter or an action, which i can use. Up to this point, i found the filter "the_content", but i don't get the post_ID or have i overlooked something? Another action, which i found is pre_get_posts. But here are the same Problem, with the Post_ID

Anyone an idea?

Greetings

Edit: I need a possibility, where i can check the login status of the user. When i visit a page, my plugin have to check, is the visitor a guest or a logged in user. Which filter/action can i use to realize them.

Edit 2: I want to write a Plugin for a Member Area. For Sport Clubs for example. This Member have no access to the Admin Area in the Wordpress Backend. It should be an own Area. Nothing edit, only view.

In Frontend should be a Point "Only for Members". When you click on this, you see a login form (except you're logged in, then you see content). In this area you can see News ONLY for Member in this Sports Club.

So, i'm searching for an action or filter, what i can use to check, is this user logged in. 
When not -> go to login form -> when true -> see content

Edit 3: It should be a complete independent Member Area and uncoupled from the wp admin Members.

Comment: Your question seems very unclear and too broad. Can you break down the problem and be more specific?

Comment: I need a possibility, where i can check the login status of the user. When i visit a page, my plugin have to check, is the visitor a guest or a logged in user. Which filter/action can i use to realize them.

Comment: I've answered your question "I need a possibility, where i can check the login status of the user. When i visit a page, my plugin have to check, is the visitor a guest or a logged in user". But your comments bring me to nowhere. I don't understand your question and it is very unclear what you are asking. I've deleted my answer and vote for close this question. Again, please describe the exact problem you have.

Comment: I want to write a Plugin for a Member Area. For Sport Clubs for example. This Member have no access to the Admin Area in the Wordpress Backend. It should be an own Area. Nothing edit, only view.

In Frontend should be a Point "Only for Members". When you click on this, you see a login form (except you're logged in, then you see content). In this area you can see News ONLY for Member in this Sports Club.

So, i'm searching for an action or filter, what i can use to check, is this user logged in. 
When not -> go to login form -> when true -> see content

I hope it's clear now

Comment: I want to check the login status of my users in my plugin, not from the wp Admins. And i'm searching for an action/filter for this problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
function restricted_access() {
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header(404);
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'restricted_access' );
```

By default, always, if the user is not logged in it will give them the 404 page. The following two functions will keep non-admins out of your Admin Panel and will also hide the black admin bar from the front-end.

```
function redirect_nonadmins(){
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ){
        wp_redirect( site_url() );
        exit;       
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_nonadmins' );

function no_adminbar() { 
    if( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'no_adminbar' );
```

**Edit** - Some explaination

The function [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) returns a true / false boolean; *True* if the user viewing the current page **is** logged in. *False* if the user viewing the current page **is not** logged in.

The function [`current_user_can()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) will check the current users capabilities. In the above I check if the current user has `administrator` capabilities. If not - do not allow them to view the admin panel and do not show the black admin bar on the front end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it should be another Member Area. Complete uncoupled from the wp admin panel. Other Member Table. Complete independent from the admin panel.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to, what is completely independent from the admin panel? Are you referring to redirects? It sounds like you want somebody to code a plugin *for* you which makes the question very broad. If you want to write a plugin yourself you need to break down your question into small specific questions.

Comment: My plugin members != wp members. It should be complete differently. My own user management.

Comment: Specifically what's your question? Are you trying *not* to use WordPress functions?

Comment: Which action/filter can i use, to check the login status.
I don't know, i'm new in the Wordpress. Perhaps is my idea bad and they're better ways to realize.

Comment: The above filters *do* check the login status. [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) function is built into WordPress which can check the login status of the current user from anywhere. [`current_user_can()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) will check the capabilities of the currently logged in user. So I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for.

Comment: Not only for the wp user's?

Comment: If you're trying to check if a *non-wordpress* user has access to certain pages, that's a little bit of a different question. How do you determine that? Is the registration system different than WordPress?

Comment: Another registration form and another login form.

Comment: Okay, i've understood and this solution is good. Thanks for this.